# Scapy sniff in monitor mode

Tags: python, network-programming, wifi, scapy

I wrote a python script using scapy to sniff TCP packets in my WIFI network and see if there was a connection between two destinations.
It works if i sniff the packets when i not in monitor mode, but when i sniff on monitor mode interface it's not working.

Any ideas how can make it work?
Snippet:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *
import time

class deferring_delete(object):
def __init__(self, d):
    self._dict = d
def __enter__(self):
    self._deletes = set()
    return self
def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
    for key in self._deletes:
        try:
            del self._dict[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass
    del self._deletes
def __delitem__(self, key):
    if key not in self._dict:
        raise KeyError(str(key))
    self._deletes.add(key)

packet_count = 0
packets = {}
accepted = {}
YOUR_IP = '10.0.0.1'
FILTER = "tcp and host not {0}".format(YOUR_IP) 

def handshake_status(packet):
    global packets,accepted,packet_count


    flag = packet[0][1].sprintf('%TCP.flags%')
    src_ip = packet[0][1].src
    dst_ip = packet[0][1].dst

    if flag == 'S':
        packets[packet_count] = {'src_ip': src_ip, 'dst_ip': dst_ip, 'time': time.ctime() , 'flag': flag} 
        print "%s ==> %s SYN_SENT" % (src_ip, dst_ip)
        packet_count += 1

    if flag == 'SA':
        for key , packet in packets.iteritems():
            if packet['src_ip'] == dst_ip:
                accepted[key] = packet

    if len(accepted) > 0:
        with deferring_delete(packets) as p:
            for key in accepted.keys():
                print "%s ==> %s ESTABLISHED" % (packets[key]['src_ip'], packets[key]['dst_ip'])
                del p[key]

        with deferring_delete(accepted) as a:
            for key in accepted.keys():
                del a[key]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sniff(iface="mon0", filter=FILTER ,prn=handshake_status)
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Are you sure the device is up? How did you set it into monitor mode?

Comment: @Yoel "line 1076, in getfield_and_val raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: src" . i used PCAP file from other linux with monitor mode on

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with the following lines:

```
flag = packet[0][1].sprintf('%TCP.flags%')
src_ip = packet[0][1].src
dst_ip = packet[0][1].dst
```

Try rewriting them as follows:

```
flag = packet.getlayer(TCP).sprintf('%TCP.flags%')
src_ip = packet.getlayer(IP).src
dst_ip = packet.getlayer(IP).dst
```